# GWT-Designer does not build Async interfaces upon addition of Remote Service

Tags: eclipse, gwt, eclipse-plugin, gwt-rpc, gwt-designer

I'm using GWT-Designer on a GWT project. It has been working well however some configuration got fouled up and it no longer builds Async interfaces and implementations when you create a new remote service. It has something to do with Eclipse Auto Build but I don't know how to see if this is enabled or how to troubleshoot it. Does anyone have experience with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the Project > Build Automatically command.